# Spark-java class not found exception

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, spark-java

I have a java project with spark and I want it to be deployed on the Tomcat server. My problem is, during Run on server in eclipse, I got error:

```
SEVERE: Exception starting filter SparkFilter
javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.myprojects.usermobility.main.UserMobilityMain
    at spark.servlet.SparkFilter.getApplication(SparkFilter.java:106)
    at spark.servlet.SparkFilter.getApplications(SparkFilter.java:131)
    at spark.servlet.SparkFilter.init(SparkFilter.java:66)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.initFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:279)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:260)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:105)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4700)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5340)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.myprojects.usermobility.main.UserMobilityMain
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1333)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1167)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at spark.servlet.SparkFilter.getApplication(SparkFilter.java:103)
    ... 14 more
```

I have specified a web.xml file as it is in spark-java tutorial for other servers. Web.xml:

```
   <filter>
        <filter-name>SparkFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>spark.servlet.SparkFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>applicationClass</param-name>
            <param-value>com.myprojects.usermobility.main.UserMobilityMain</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>SparkFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
```

Also I added things that are needed in java class. UserMobilityMain.java :

```
package com.myprojects.usermobility.main;

import spark.Request;
import spark.Spark;
import spark.servlet.SparkApplication;

public class UserMobilityMain implements SparkApplication {  

    @Override
    public void init() { ... } // there are specified mappings
}
```

I tried to use only java class name in web.xml but it is not working either. I checked in war file and in folder WEB-INF/class there are appropriate .class files. I am using Tomcat 8.0 and Java 1.8. I am also including maven config file. Pom.xml :

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>UserMobilityWeb</groupId>
  <artifactId>UserMobilityWeb</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <build>
  <finalName>UserMobilityWeb</finalName>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.7.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.0</version>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sparkjava</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20171018</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.squareup.okhttp3</groupId>
            <artifactId>okhttp</artifactId>
            <version>3.9.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.39</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Also I tried to build through maven and move war file to webapps folder in Tomcat server, but it still gives same error in Tomcat log files.

EDIT: I also have previous war file of this project that is working, but I need to do some changes in code and build new one.

Comment: Try to remove `com.myprojects.usermobility.` from web.xml. I've compared with my web.xml and I don't have that part, but we might just have different project structure.

Comment: @SHG I tried many combinations of packages in web.xml and all of them gives the same ouput so it must be some problem with linking .class files, but I can't find where it can be repaired.